# Laravel 5.4 show message that email is not registered on login form

Tags: laravel-5, authentication

In my Laravel 5.4 project, I am using built in auth login/register provided by Laravel.

Everything is working well. Anyway, I would like to show message saying that *This email: someemail@domain.com is not yet registered in our database* on the login form.

Could you please advise on how to achieved this?

Comment: You know it is a security risk to do this?

Comment: you will need to query the user table where email equals `someemail@domain.com` ===> `$user = User::where('email', 'someemail@domain.com')-> get();` and test `if($user->empty()){//return OK to use this email}` ;)

Comment: @justkidding96 Thank you for your alert. I forgot about the security problem.

Comment: @Maraboc Thanks for your help